# Extreme memory leak from jQuery player

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, jplayer

I have a jQuery jplayer on my page and i'm getting reports that the page is sluggish and when my friends inspecting chrome process in task manager the memory demand climbs up to 1 gig and higher.

I cant pinpoint the problem in the page and i'm not receiving any unusual error on console either.

[The Player Page](http://www.tranceil.fm/player)

- Warning: Music is played in auto mode upon launch

Any thoughts?

Comment: http://www.jplayer.org/support/

Comment: It stays around 110Mb for me, but with a CPU Load of 15%